# What object can be the starting point in github Graphql api?

Tags: rest, api, github, graph, graphql

I have been investigating the graphql API call these days.

I have completed the tutorial of GitHub.

My question is that there must be some starting point for each graphql call.

in https://developer.github.com/v4/guides/using-the-explorer/

```
# the starting point is the object viewer 

query {
      viewer {
        login
        name
      }
    }
```

in https://developer.github.com/v4/guides/forming-calls/

```
# the starting point is the object repository

query {
  repository(owner:"octocat", name:"Hello-World") {
    issues(last:20, states:CLOSED) {
      edges {
        node {
          title
          url
          labels(first:5) {
            edges {
              node {
                name
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What is the **set** of the possible objects which can be the starting point of a **"query"** or **"mutation"** in GraphQl call in **Github** ?

It seems the whole documentation of Github didn't mention this.

Comment: https://developer.github.com/v4/guides/intro-to-graphql/#discovering-the-graphql-api

Comment: @jonrsharpe appreciate if you could explain a little bit more, it seems that  the link you provided is just emphasizing that "This means you can query a GraphQL schema for details about itself."  It doesn't explain what could be the starting point of any graphql call

Comment: Did you try exactly the query they're suggesting? There's even an interactive way to do it, just click the "Run in Explorer" link.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have tried almost all queries in the tutorial in the Github browser, that's exactly why I come up with this question. But However, you seem not answering my question.

Comment: Are we looking at the same thing? I can see a list with the description *"The query root of GitHub's GraphQL interface"* that lists all of the entry points, including `repository` and `viewer` from your examples. They're also listed in e.g. https://developer.github.com/v4/query/#fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Go to Github GraphQL API explorer in [here](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/)
2. Login and click the `Docs` button in the top-right corner
3. Click the `Query` or `Mutation` and it will show you all the available fields of the root Query and Mutation (i.e. starting point in your terminology) :

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so now it is quite clear that the list of the possible root(starting point) for __Mutations__.  But for the__[Query](http://example.com)__, there are two parts in that page, "Connection" and "Fields", which of them are the possible root?

Comment: The `Connection` and `Fields` in the Query  document page is only the sub-header of that document and they are nothing to do with GraphQL .If you pay more attention to the document , all the fields of the root query are also listed in there.